# Eliminar valores de una lista de listas

Tags: python, python-3.x

¿Cómo puedo eliminar los valores dobles que salen en algunas listas?

```
def selection_and_reproduction(poblacionNueva):

puntuados = [ [calcularFitness(i), i] for i in poblacionNueva] #Calcula el fitness de cada individuo, y lo guarda en pares ordenados de la forma (5 , [1,2,1,1,4,1,8,9,4,1])
def takeSecond(puntuados):
    return puntuados[0]
puntuados = sorted(puntuados, key=takeSecond) 

print("Puntuados:\n%s"%(puntuados))
poblacionNueva = puntuados
selected =  puntuados[(len(puntuados)-indAReproducir):] 

lista = list(range(1, largo))
print("LISTA:\n%s"%(lista))
random.shuffle(lista)
print("LISTA ALEATORIA:\n%s"%(lista))
for i in lista: 
    i = i-1
    punto =lista[i] 

    padre = random.sample(selected, 2)

    print("Punto:%s"%(punto))
    print("Padre:%s"%(padre))

    poblacionNueva[i][:punto] = (padre[0])[1][:punto] 
    print("Primera parte:%s"%(poblacionNueva[i][:punto]))

    poblacionNueva[i][punto:] = (padre[1])[1][punto:]
    print("Segunda parte:%s"%(poblacionNueva[i][punto:]))

    i = poblacionNueva[i][:punto] + poblacionNueva[i][punto:]
    print("Individuo Generado:%s"%(i))
    print("Fitness de I:%s"%(calcularFitness(i)))
    print("Individuo Generado CON FITNESS:%s"%(i))

poblacionNueva = [i for i in poblacionNueva]
print("Poblacion Nueva FINAL:\n%s"%(poblacionNueva))
return poblacionNueva
```

Habría que *eliminar* el valor de las dos *ultimas listas* de **PoblacionNueva**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EDIT 1:
He utilizado tanto el Del como el pop. Me elimina el valor pero me deja el espacio vacio de la primera lista en las dos ultimas que necesito eliminarlo tambien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A ver si te entendí: tienes dos listas, hay elementos que aparecen en las dos y desea eliminar estos de ambas?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Si, fijate en la solucion `PoblacionNuevaFinal`. Quiero eliminar ese valor 1 y 2 q está en la primera lista de ambas. He intentado con .pop pero, a pesar de eliminar el numero, me deja el espacio vacio.

Comment: He editado con los cambios @PatricioMoracho

Answer (score 1):

para el tratamiento de "listas" en python, existe la funcion "pop()", la que elimina un elemento segun su indice (ubicación en lista).

por ejemplo:

```
lista = [4,5,1]
lista.pop(0)
```

quitara el primer elemento de la lista, quedando como resultado [5,1] (en python, el primer indice de las listas es 0 [cero])

```
lista = [4,5,1]
lista.pop(1)
```

quitara el segundo elemento de la lista, quedando como resultado [4,1]

espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Si no tienes listas excesivamente grandes, en vez de eliminar puedes filtrar y crear nuevas versiones de las dos listas de la siguiente forma:

```
# Vamos a eliminar el elemento [4, 5, 3, 0, 4] que está en ambas listas
lista1 = [[5, 0, 3, 7, 3], [4, 5, 3, 0, 4]]           # poblacionNueva
lista2 = [[0, [4, 5, 3, 0, 4]], [2, [9, 6, 7, 7, 9]]] # puntuados

lista1new = [e for e in lista1 if e not in [e[1] for e in lista2]]
lista2new = [e for e in lista2 if e[1] not in lista1]

print(lista1new)
print(lista2new)
[[5, 0, 3, 7, 3]]
[[2, [9, 6, 7, 7, 9]]]
```

Básicamente filtramos los elementos de la primer lista que estuvieran en la segunda, hay que hacer una segunda operación de comprensión, por que la segunda lista tiene una estructura distinta del tipo `[a, [b, c, d, e, f]` y luego simplemente hacemos lo mismo con los elementos de la segunda lista.

Comment: No es eso lo que quiero. Mira el Edit 1.

Comment: Carlos, evidentemente no te entendí. A ver si esto es lo que quieres: tienes una lista `[0, [4, 5, 3, 0, 4]]` y la quieres transformar en `[4, 5, 3, 0, 4]`?

Answer (score 0):

solo tienes que hacer esto:

```
    lista = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8]]
    lista = list[1:-1]
    #eliminaria el primer y ultimo valor
    [[4,5]]

    lista2=[1,2,3,4,5]
    lista2 = [1:-1]
#eliminaria el primer y ultimo valor
    [2,3,4]
```

referencia:
[slicing python](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html)